# PDO prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-injection

I know that PDO prepared statements should be used to avoid SQL injection. Must it always have this format:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table where id = :id');
$stmt->execute( array(':id' => $_GET['id']) );
```

or will any of the following formats negate SQL injection too?

*VERSION 1*

```
$queryString = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ".$_GET['id'];
$stmt= $db->prepare($queryString);  
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

*VERSION 2*

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ".$_GET['id']);
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: By inserting the id within the string, you are somewhat negating the point of adding parameters in the way that PDO does.  The two examples would probably work - you can test this more easily yourself - but the first is the only one really where it would prevent injection

Comment: Will this code work? Did you TRY it?

Comment: Bound parameters are used to avoid sql injection not prepared statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind your variables like you do in your first code.  The `Version 1` and `Version 2` codes are both **INSECURE**.